# Node and npm is not recognized after install node using nvm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

**First** I installed nvm.

then I tried `nvm-v` and it gives me the version.

After that I installed node.js `nvm install 6.10.0`

It also succeeded.

But when I try to `npm-v` `node-v` both are not recognized.

**I thinks the installed path isn't recognized by the system.**
How do I resolve this error?

When I try `nvm use 6.10.0` it gives me this error

[image]

**I'm using Windows 8.1**

Comment: You need to mention OS as well

Comment: It's Windows 8.1 =)

Answer (score 1):

> Note: nvm does not support Windows (see #284). Two alternatives exist, which are neither supported nor developed by us:
>    - nvm-windows
>    - nodist

source: [nvm readme](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#install-script)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use NVM versions 8.* ones. That should solve the problem. I am using Windows only.

If you face issues, you can follow up below steps.

1. Go to Control Panel, Add or Remove Programs. Repair NodeJS.
2. Go to CMD ( Command Line ), run ng serve or npm install to verify.
3. If still issue, run **nvm off**
4. Then run  **ng serve or npm install**
5. Run **nvm on**
6. Now run **ng serve or npm install**. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
nvm use nodejs_version
```

This command resolved my issue

Answer (score -1):

Please try these links. Many people found that it helps. Note, NVM must be installed before NodeJS.

[TechBrij](https://techbrij.com/nvm-windows-node-npm-not-recognized) & [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-windows)